DS1110S delay line output signal operation
Given 0-3.3V pulse input to a DS1110S operating on Vcc=5V, how can I know the delayed output signal amplitude?
Is it 0-3.3 like the input or 0-5V?
The Voh data in the table is not clear.


The amplitude information is lost in the first delay stage, only the timing information is forwarded along the chain.
VOH depends on VCC and the load current. This IC is designed to drive TTL inputs, so the sink current capability is much higer than the provided source current on output high level.
ADDED to answer some questions in the comments:
From the output characteristics in the datasheet of the DS1110S I think the output stage is probably similar to the totem pole output of a 74S00 family gate. I may be wrong here.
I tried to implement a simulation of this circuit using the CircuitLab simulator. The fastest NPN transistor 2N5179 there is a lot slower than the transistors inside the chip, but it may help to understand the expected signal form.
The non saturating darlington stage Q6, Q3 provides the source current, the output voltage is limited by the relation between R2 and R6. So it depends on Vcc of the chip.
The datasheet guarantees a Voh of 2.4 V at high level output with 1 mA of load current. I don't know the internal circuit, bit I guess there is a similar resistive divider.
Q2 provides high sink current and Q7 seams to prohibit saturation for fast turn off.
I added R5 as pullup resistor to raise the high level up to 5 V just for a test. It does not help very much to speed up the rising edge and is not needed to drive a 74ABT04 input.
I assume in the real world circuit the connection will propagate the signal within 1 ns, but I cannot prove that. I don't know the application, but if this is relevant, a wider look for other clock generation and distribution ICs with available simulator models may be useful.

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

Hello Jens,I understand that if we have some load current then automatically we know do I*Rload and this is Vout,How Vcc plays a role here? Thanks.

VCC just sets the upper range of Vout.

Hello Jens,I dont have a spice model of this component. The load is a circuit which is makes manipulations of that pulse.the output of this conponent will be connected directly to zenner diode and capacitor as shown in the photo of the link.My circuit expects 0-3.3V signal.Suppose the load impedance will not be 0-3.3V. How can I tweak the output of the DS1110S so i will get the desired signal at the input of my circuit?
https://ibb.co/vBQbtLG

The outputs of this IC have strong sink and weak source capabilities. So better think of them as a kind of open collector outputs and add a pullup resistor and a clamping zener diode of 3.3 V.

Hello Jens,Yes the pullup current is 12 times stronger.
Suppose  the load of the DS1110S is  74ABT04 Hex inverter.
I have 0-3.3V going into the DS1110S and its output is going into hex inverter 74ABT04.
I dont have the spice models.A pullup resistor will be placed between them.
The pullup resistor  will be connected to 5V.What is the proper process of knowing my load HEX inverter gets a good 0-3.3V at the input?
Thanks.
https://assets.nexperia.com/documents/data-sheet/74ABT04.pdf

The 74ABT04 needs a 5 V supply and you can directy connect an input to a DS1110 output. There is no need to create 3.3 V signal levels between them.

Hello Jens, Why you are not worried about the input signal then the load is 74ABT04.Why in the case of the output of DS1110S connected to 74ABT04 there is no need for pull resistor between them? Thanks.

I don't understand your question. These both are TTL level compatible ICs, made to be simply connected. This has nothing to do with the DS1110S inputs. You would only add a, say 1 kohm, pullup resistor to force a faster rising edge, which may be useful at very critical timings.

Hello Jens, How do you see that they are compatible.
How do you see that in their datasheets that they are compatible?
Thanks.

Maybe there is a fundamental misunderstanding of the internal circuit of the DS1110S. It is not an anlog delay line, but a chain of digital buffers. You can achieve the same by chaining a lot of DM74S08 gates.

The datasheet says "Each tap is capable of driving up to ten 74LS type loads". The input capacitance of 74ABT04 is in the ballpark of an LS-TTL input, but the current is much lower. So, to more closely emulate a LS TTL input you can add a pullup resistor. Ioh of -1 mA and Iol of 12 mA is typical for a so called "totem pole" output stage as used in TTL chips.

Hello Jens,The input capacitance of the 74ABT04 is 3pf .I  tried to look in the data sheet below but I could not see the input capacitance of the 74LS.How do you know what is the capacitance of the 74LS?
Also regarding the term "driving" , for me its the rate of charging of the load capacitor,It depends on I=CdV/dt.T.How to know based on the currents and the load capacitance of the 3pf .What math involved so we get the desired voltage at the desired time.Is there such a thing in out situation?
Thanks.
https://www.futurlec.com/IC74LS00Series.shtml
https://www.futurlec.com/74LS/74LS00.shtml

Hello Jens, Why did you say that the output of 74ABT04  is VCC, in the data sheet Voh=2.5V
